# 16.04 > SSH client slow in remote server

Tags: networking, ssh

I've got a fresh new laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm experiencing slowdown problem in console/terminal when connecting in ssh in a remote server: connexion is slow and typing char has some delays.

The connection ssh log (-vvv) have no "failure" or "error" messages

Cannot update server's UseDNS and sshd_config (unix.stackexchange.com/a/6230/70524)

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's `UseDNS` and `sshd_config` (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6230/70524).

Comment: I don't want to (and cannot) update  all server(s) configurations

Comment: If the server is configured to do so, that's what you will have to do.

Comment: this problem only occurs w. my new laptop, all was fine with previous one

Comment: have you tried running your ssh connection with some -v options to get more info on when it might be renogtiating or otherwise having issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved w. a recent Ubuntu update, no problem anymore!

Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you know what changed? The most recent SSH update was on May 10: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+publishinghistory

Comment: Unfortunatly, I've no idea at all of what has solved my issue!